How can I fix my cursor in the middle position, while I using VS code for coding?
How can I fix my cursor in the middle position, while I using VS code for coding?
When I writing code simultaniously my mouse pointer move down,hence I can't see my code below. That's I hate most in VS code , Here, one more problem in MVN References, I also need to hide it ! It's really annoying while coding! Especially myself!
Advanced Thanks For your valuable time.
Happy Stackoverflow.
I want to fix my cursor in the middle position, while I using VS code for coding.
